# Facebook Single Sign On (SSO) on Android closes intent the moment it is activated

Tags: android, facebook

I bound a login button to the facebook.authorize() method, of which I expect it to open the intent to the Facebook SSO Activity. I tapped on it, it does change screen (animation shown), but closes back to my original activity. So it opens and closes, and nothing happens.

```
private void initFacebook() {
    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        }
    });
}

private void initLoginButton() {
    ImageButton loginButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            initFacebook();
        }
    });
}
```

May I know what is happening here? I do have Facebook app installed on my phone. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: if I forced it to use Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH , it works, weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably not implementing the onActivityResult as described in the same question: [Android Facebook.authorize don't call oncomplete method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458004/android-facebook-authorize-dont-call-oncomplete-method)