# Android Facebook SSO does not work when fb is already installed on device

Tags: android, facebook, hash, single-sign-on

I want to implement Single Sign On with Facebook in an android application. I have the following problem:

I can receive access token and all the data I need when the facebook app is not installed on device. But when I install the facebook application nothing seems to work. When I launch the activity that implements SSO it just loads for a while and then it is paused without returning anything.

I have a signed apk and I think I have the right hash key in the fb developers page.

Does anyone know why could this problem appear? Is there something I need to change in the facebook android sdk?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit:
I tried what YShinkarev said here -> [Android - facebook sdk Login window disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764777/android-facebook-sdk-login-window-disappear) (commenting some lines in facebook.java code and disabling SSO). Now I give credentials and receive access token. But shouldn't it be that I received it automatically if I was signed in from the fb app? I do not understand why this does not work..

Comment: Log out the messages passed back from FB in the auth listener and post them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a problem with the android SSO, and it has been acknowledged by facebook as you can see in the [Platform Status page](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status).

If the facebook application is present on the device then the SSO is used and it won't work until facebook fixes the problem.
There are some other threads here about this problem, for example: [logging in to facebook from my app works on emulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249889/logging-in-to-facebook-from-my-app-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-device)

Comment: Any update on this? The SSO issue is no longer on the Platform Status, but is still does not seem to work

Comment: It was fixed a while ago as far as I'm aware. Have you tried asking a new question?

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer i am facing the same problem and i have asked a new question for that also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215610/facebook-login-in-andorid-with-different-devices

Comment: are there any fixes for this?